# GCM PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR on ICS

Tags: android, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I have migrated my app to use the new GCM push system. It works fine for thousand of users but today I got a user with a Samsung Galaxy S3 with ICS that gets a PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR every time he tries to register.

I can see that others has that problem on AVD's but what does it mean on a real device?

How can I debug further / find out what goes wrong in the registration process?

P.S. yes I did read http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html where it says PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR   Incorrect phone registration with Google. This phone doesn't currently support GCM. but this is obviously not correct since GCM works on many other S3's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that this users phone is rooted and running a ROM in which for some reason GCM is not working?

Comment: Good point, so I just asked the user. The phone is rooted with a stock ROM but the user has a google account on the phone and google play works just fine. And as far as I know the google push system is integrated with the play account.

Comment: Hmm..... Stock ROM *should* work but who knows what tweaks could have been made. I'm really not sure what to say at this point. Although now you have a way out, "Rooted devices are not supported" :)

Comment: Well, the user installed another ROM and everything started working again. So I suppose it was a bad ROM.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not surprised to be honest, except for the fact that it sounds like _only_ your app was the one that wasn't working. You'd think if the ROM had bad GCM code that most apps would break. Oh well, not your fault!

Comment: Yup - I agree it sounds weird. I still think my code is OK since it runs on some hundred thousand devices :-) - anyway - problem solved, cannot reproduce, moving on to the next bugs... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after seraching on the internet for many days I noticed this in the google groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cerberus-support-forum/eJxOsYqkTxo)  and tried it and it worked flawlessly for me.

There is something wrong with your Google account. Please try this:

- Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All

or

Go to Settings -> Apps-> All  (on newer versions)

- Select "Clear data" for "Google Play services" and "Google services framework"
- Reboot the phone

Then check for the GCM id from your app.

If it still doesn't work then remove all your google accounts from the phone and reboot the phone and add the account again.

It worked for me (after implementing many solutions that I got from searching the internet.)

Hope it helps!!